# Environment specific Chef databags

Tags: chef-infra

I'm trying to determine the best method for databags, my hold-up being I don't see why I can't just include a single databag containing everything per environment.  I'm finding that having individual databags for cookbooks seems to be the norm.

My initial understanding was this:

dev.json

```
- mysql_password: 234983
- mysql_user: heyhey
- mysql_host: somewhere.com
- newrelic_api: something
```

uat.json

```
- mysql_password: 111113
- mysql_user: root
- mysql_host: somewhere-else.com
- newrelic_api: something-else
```

attributes/default.rb

```
- load <chef-env> databag
- mysql_password = databag.item.mysql_password
```

Is this a bad method or are their any caveats to doing it this way?

Comment: Besides that I would not put the logic to read the data bag into the attributes file, this sounds legit.

Comment: I prefer to have data bags for each cookbook separated. This allows me to re-use the cookbooks in other setups without having to rely on the "base data bag reader/mapper" in the run_list. Also if you use community cookbooks which are configured by node attributes, you'll have to write a wrapper cookbook anyways to map your data bag data to the attributes. This should belong into the wrapper cookbook and not into a single "Mapping"-Cookbook. However, when I have an "app-cookbook" that wraps several pieces together, I use per-app data bags e.g. "apps/railsapp_production.json"

Comment: a good example for app-cookbooks/data bag is https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/supermarket by Chef, Inc.

Comment: http://docs.chef.io/data_bags.html#with-environments